# HTTPS with Clack

Tags: ssl, common-lisp, hunchentoot

I have written a small server with [Ningle](https://github.com/fukamachi/ningle), which in turn is using [Clack](https://github.com/fukamachi/clack) to start a web server such as Hunchentoot or Woo.

### How can I handle HTTPS requests ?

I have of course obtained the needed certificates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That was in fact quite simple.

`(clack:clackup <server> :ssl t :ssl-key-file <path to file> :ssl-cert-file <path to file>)`

---

Note: I understand from [this issue](https://github.com/fukamachi/clack/issues/75) that Woo does not yet support SSL, however at least Hunchentoot does.

Comment: I hope somebody will run into this problem and find this example.

Comment: Self-answers are welcome (and even encouraged), thanks for contributing. You can of also accept your own answer (green mark).

Comment: @coredump I know that, I am familiar with other sites of the network. Thanks anyway ;)